# How to break out of an if statement from a boolean inside the if statement

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I have something like this

```
bool a = true;
bool b = true;
bool plot = true;
if(plot)
{
    if(a)
    {
        if(b)
            b = false;
        else
            b = true;
    //do some meaningful stuff here
    }
//some more stuff here that needs to be executed
}
```

I want to break out of the if statement that tests a when b turns false. Kind of like break and continue in loops. Any ideas?
Edit: sorry forgot to include the big if statement. I want to break out of if(a) when b is false but not break out of if(plot).

Comment: As in -- `if(!b) break;`?

Comment: This makes no sense.  There is nothing to "break" out from.  This is not a loop. Either the precondition for a is true prior to executing the "if(a)" and the code in the statement is executed, or it is false, and the code is not executed.  Please re-write your question.

Comment: This looks like quite enough logic to be put in a method of itself. So you could just `return` from that.

Comment: just put brackets around your inner if like your outer if.  And you will 'break' out.  I think you are overthinking.

Comment: Actually, that happens by default!

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance that

Comment: Use `goto label`  (joking)

Comment: To b or !b, that is the question.

Comment: @NewDev - since that was an actual answer (which was quickly deleted because of downvotes; so i don't mean you directly): if `goto` is the solution, you have more problems than you are aware of. It's a very good indicator to start refactoring immediately!

Comment: @Corak, that's my subtle hint at the OP's problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(plot)
{
    if(a)
    {
        b= !b;
        if( b )
        {
            //do something meaningful stuff here
        }
    }
    //some more stuff here that needs to be executed
}
```

Comment: Needs more if nesting!

Comment: Was going for minimal change from the original.

Answer (score 13):

You can extract your logic into separate method. This will allow you to have maximum one level of ifs:

```
private void Foo()
{
   bool a = true;
   bool b = true;
   bool plot = true;

   if (!plot)
      return;

   if (a)
   {
      b = !b;
      //do something meaningful stuff here
   }

   //some more stuff here that needs to be executed   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
bool a = true;
bool b = true;
bool plot = true;
if(plot && a)
{
  if (b)
    b = false
  else
    b = true;

  if (b)
  {
    //some more stuff here that needs to be executed
  }
}
```

This should do what you want ..

Comment: Guys, are you kidding? This is not same logic as in question