# How to break out of an IF statement

Tags: c#, .net

I have code like this:

```
public void Method()
{
    if(something)
    {
        // Some code
        if(something2)
        {
            // Now I should break from ifs and go to the code outside ifs
        }
        return;
    }
    // The code I want to go if the second if is true
}
```

Is there a possibility to go to that code after *if*s without using any go to statement or extracting rest of the code to the other method?

---

Yes, I know Else ;) 
But this code is farly long and should be run IF the first IF is false and when the first IF is true *and* the second is false.
So extracting a method I think is the best idea.

Comment: In the given code an `else` might be enough. Bu tin general you should structure your code so that you don't need this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727655/how-to-break-out-of-an-if-statement-from-a-boolean-inside-the-if-statement

Comment: "_So extracting method I think is best Idea_" Exactly.

Comment: I'm looking for clever answers to this question, other than else. You should change title to like "break out deeply nested ifs" or something. Otherwise, you'll just get unwanted downvotes by people who don't read.

Comment: The bit of code you've given is too simple and can simply be changed with `else` or `!something2` etc. So your code really won't help get a good answer. I suggest to give a better example or post your actual code.

Comment: It sounds more as though you need to look into restructuring your logic, you haven't really explained why `else return;` isn't a viable option

Comment: @szpic Could you please unmark my answer and select the one with moreupvotes? Because, his answer is more appropriate for your case.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sometimes that isn't possible without excessively nested `if` statements because the language lacks a suitable control-structure. I find it perplexing that we have so many different control-structures for loops (`for`, `foreach`, `foreach(await)`, `while`, and `do`) when they all can be reduced `while`, while we still only have one kind of conditional branch `if`. What I want to see is something like `try/catch` but without an exception: like a  _scoped_-`return` or allow the `continue` keyword in an `if` block.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
public void Method()
{
    do
    {
        if (something)
        {
            // some code
            if (something2)
            {
                break;
            }
            
            return;
        }
        break;
    }
    while( false );

    // The code I want to go if the second `if` is true
}
```

Comment: yet it's the only one that truly answered OP's question.

Comment: Wrong, in C# break only breaks you out of an enclosing loop or switch statement.  It will not break you out of an if block.

Comment: @user2163234 I think you're misunderstanding his solution. He wrapped the `if` in an otherwise-meaningless `while` loop. So `break` breaks out of the `while` loop, which is functionally equivalent to breaking out of the `if` (since the `if` is the only child of the `while`.

Comment: That said, if you find yourself wanting to do something like this, please reconsider and refactor your code instead.

Comment: @Matthew my mistake.

Comment: Worked fine for me. Be careful to keep the last break outside all IFs tho otherwise your code will overflow.

Comment: @SylkerTeles I was so stupid. I should have written `do { ... }while(false);`. :p

Comment: IMO better to replace 'while(true){' with 'switch (0) { case 0:' to avoid problems with the 'continue' statement being hijacked by the former.

Comment: @cshu Why not edit this to include one of the safer options with less risk of an accidental infinite loop?

Comment: @Rob Mosher: Probably because they think they are on a forum (where editing is an unknown concept).

Answer (score 28):

You can use a goto to drop past some code. In the example, if thing1 is true then the check for things2 is bypassed.

```
if (something) {
    do_stuff();
    if (thing1) { 
        do_thing1();
        goto SkipToEnd;
    }
    if (thing2) {
        do_thing2();
    }
SkipToEnd:
    do_thing3();
}
```

Comment: The concept of "without using gotos" is nonsense or a homework problem. You use what is available to do the job, that makes your code clear to the next reader. Artificial constructs to avoid an obvious solution help no one. Gotos should ideally only be used to go forward in code, never into another method, and never for looping.

Answer (score 20):

This is a variation of something I learned several years back.  Apparently, this is popular with C++ developers.

First off, I think I know why you want to break out of IF blocks.  For me, I don't like a bunch of nested blocks because 1) it makes the code look messy and 2) it can be a [PITA](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PITA#Noun) to maintain if you have to move logic around.

Consider a `do/while` loop instead:

```
public void Method()
{
    bool something = true, something2 = false;

    do
    {
        if (!something)
            break;

        if (something2)
            break;

    } while (false);
}
```

The `do/while` loop is guaranteed to run only once just like an IF block thanks to the hardcoded `false` condition.  When you want to exit early, just `break`.

Comment: Since this is still getting upvotes, I may as well mention my love/hate relationship with this method. Normally, if you have an IF statement within a loop, you can use `break` within the IF block to break out of the parent loop. However, if you use the technique in my answer here, the aforementioned inner IF would be replaced by a loop, so using `break` within that would just break you out of your "IF loop", leaving you still within the main loop.

Answer (score 15):

```
public void Method()
{
    if(something)
    {
        // Some code
        if(something2)
        {
            // Now I should break from ifs and go to the code outside ifs
           goto done;
        }
        return;
    }
    // The code I want to go if the second if is true
    done: // etc.
}
```

[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727655/how-to-break-out-of-an-if-statement-from-a-boolean-inside-the-if-statement?lq=1)

[Long answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7805b4b9-f778-4f04-a58a-b889d1395cf7/nested-if-statement-use-break-to-break-out-of-if-statment-only?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: I gave this answer a +1 because of the [supporting evidence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/goto) from Microsoft, specifically:

"The `goto` statement is also useful to get out of deeply nested loops."

Answer (score 5):

Another way starting from C# 7.0 would be using local functions. You could name the local function with a meaningful name, and call it directly before declaring it (for clarity). Here is your example rewritten:

```
public void Method()
{
    // Some code here
    bool something = true, something2 = true;

    DoSomething();
    void DoSomething()
    {
        if (something)
        {
            // Some code
            if (something2)
            {
                // Now I should break from ifs and go to the code outside ifs
                return;
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    // The code I want to go if the second if is true
    // More code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, insert a single `else`:

```
public void Method()
{
    if(something)
    {
        // Some code
        if(something2)
        {
            // Now I should break from ifs and go to the code outside ifs
        }
        else 
            return;
    }
    // The code I want to go if the second if is true
}
```

Generally: There is no `break` in an `if/else` sequence, simply arrange your code correctly in `if / if else / else` clauses.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void Method()
{
    if(something)
    {
        // Some code
        if(!something2)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    // The code I want to go if the second if is true
}
```

Comment: Old answer but for future viewers thinking this is a simple solution, return breaks out of Method() too, so the code OP wanted to run (as it is outside of the if statements, but inside the same method).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Method()
{
    if(something)
    {
        // Some code
        if(something2)
        {
            // The code I want to go if the second if is true
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `return` only if `!something2` or use `else return`:

```
public void Method()
{
    if(something)
    {
        //some code
        if(something2)
        {
            //now I should break from ifs and go to the code outside ifs
        }
        if(!something2) // or else
            return;
    }
    // The code I want to go if the second if is true
}
```

Comment: The only reason to do that instead of simply using an `else` is if the body of the inner `if`could change `something2`.

Comment: @CompuChip: good point, so either use `!something2` or `else`.

Comment: You don't even need the first `if` if it returns when false. Just check `if (!something2)` and `return`. The example code is too simple and obviously not his real problem. Unless he's a complete noob......

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a lambda

```
if (new Func<bool>(() =>
{
    if (something1)
    {
        // Some code that calculates "something2"
        if (something2)
        {
            // Now I should break from ifs and go to the code outside ifs
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
})())
{
    // The code I want to go if the second if is true
}
```

P.S. I think I know why people would want this. "Run stuff if all conditions are true, otherwise run other stuff". And the conditions are too complicated to put into one `if` or they depend one on another.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., how does it solve the problem? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56360579/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, you should simply run the code after the *ifs* inside the second *if* instead (or set a flag like someone else mentioned, depending on the context). Use method calls to improve readability and reduce nesting.

As for actually escaping *ifs*, I think there is a way that conforms much more to C# standards than the answers I've seen here. Simply extract the contents of the *if* statement to a separate method. This also increases readability. So:

```
public void Method()
{
    if(something)
    {
        //some code
        if (somethingelse)
        {
            //break if
        }

        //some other code running if the above if didn't trigger
    }
}
```

This can be accomplished as such:

```
public void Method()
{
    if(something)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}

public void DoSomething()
{
    //some code
    if (somethingelse)
    {
        return;
    }

    //some other code running if the above if didn't trigger
}
```

Comment: The old-school programmer in me cringes at the use of all those calls and stack popping, but of course our magic compilers today will make this efficient, and we don't sweat a few cycles anymore. :)

Comment: @Engineer Heh, today Readability is king :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a control variable:

```
public void Method()
{
    bool doSomethingElse = true;
    if(something)
    {
        // Some code
        if(!something2)
        {
            doSomethingElse = false;
        }
    }
    if(doSomethingElse)
    {
        // The code I want to go if the second if is true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant that may be really useful in more complicated cases:

```
try {
    if (something)
    {
        // Some code
        if (something2)
        {
            throw new Exception("Weird-01.");
            // Now you will go to the catch statement
        }
        if (something3)
        {
            throw new Exception("Weird-02.");
            // Now you will go to the catch statement
        }
        // Some code
        return;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex); // You will get your Weird-01 or Weird-02 here
}
// The code I want to go if the second or third if is true
```

Comment: [Is it “bad” to use try-catch for flow control in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1336094/719186)

Comment: Yes, Lars, don't use try-catch to organize simple if-else, but You "can" ))).

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (contREsponse == "yes")
                {
                    cont = true;
                }
                else if (contREsponse == "no")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Come back, when you change your mind.");                    
                    //exit environment:  
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
```